# Fix objects inside subview into place

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-autolayout

How can I fix objects inside a view to a position? What I mean is: I have a subview which includes multiple elements for example an image and a textfield. Those subviews mustn't change their aspect ratio. I know I can set that via auto-layout. But how can I set that all the elements in the subview stick relative to their position inside of that subview? So that if I resize the subview (while remaining in their aspect ratio) the content of it will look the same just up- or downscaled?

[image: Schematic]

Thank you!

---

**UPDATE:** This is how it looks like. The white area in the middle is the 'subview', and the textfield together with the labels the 'content':

[image: This is how it looks like. The white area in the middle is the 'subview', and the textfield together with the labels the 'content'.]

Now if the screen size of the device changes it looks like that:

[image: Now if the screen size of the device changes it looks like that:]

I have a constraint saying that the 'subview' should keep its aspect ratio. And I just want the 'content' to resize accordingly.
If I try to auto-layout the textfields and labels to 'subview' I get many weird errors. Isn't there any easier method? I mean it's just resizing and not some complex UI changes.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried but, if you are scaling your view then inner views are will scale in ratio of the outer view.

But if your plan is to stretch outer view from the corners may be this layout setting can be help full.

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer. Could you take a look at it again, please? I tried to explain it better this time. :)

Comment: @wyte Your problem is simple than I thought. Just implement same constraint which I suggested and you will be fine. This time make textfield vertical spacing-with respect to each other and trailing space from container.

Comment: For me the content still behaves strange and I get some conflicting constraint errors. Could you show me the whole sidebar on the left or send me the project, please? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the storyboard you have an option to give something the same height or width as the parentView if you ctrl + pull to it.

Then it will say x equal to parent y = 1 whewre 1 is 100% of size, size it down to for example 95% and the align the views in the center, left or right or wherever you would like.